# Clion memory view

Tags: c++, memory, clion

I can't find a memory view in Jetbrain's clion IDE. 
Does anybody know to show it (has clion this feature)?

Meant is this: [memory view](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_memoryview.htm) in eclipse

Comment: If you know how V-R displays the memory then please tell.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Memory View has been added to [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/download/download-thanks.html) in version [2019.1](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CLION/Release+notes). To open it, select a pointer variable in the debugger’s variables view and press `Ctrl+Enter` on Windows/Linux or `⌘Enter` on macOS.

---

In all earlier versions you can use the debugger's command `x` which is available in both [GDB and LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html). You can choose the debugger via *CLion->Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->Toolchains->Debugger*, and display the Debug window via *View->Tool Windows->Debug* or it should appear if you start a new debugging session via *Run->Debug*.

For example, in the Debug window I can eXplore memory starting at the address of a variable `i`:

```
(lldb) x &i
0x7fff59dbac58: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 ac db 59 ff 7f 00 00  ...........Y....
0x7fff59dbac68: 5e 30 2f 61 ff 7f 00 00 88 ac db 59 ff 7f 00 00  ^0/a.......Y....
```

Comment: "For example in the Debugger window I can display memory starting at the address of a variable i:" how do you do this?

Answer (score 12):

Not exactly memory view, but the following proved extremely useful for me. If you have a variable like `char *p` then you can add `(char[100])p` to watches and see 100 characters in memory beginning from `p`.

Answer (score 4):

Memory view is a built in feature as of [Clion 2019.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/whatsnew/).

You can access it by selecting a pointer in the debugger list and pressing either `⌘Enter` on Mac or `Ctrl+Enter` on Windows/Linux.

From the "What's New" page:

> Memory View dumps the memory behind the pointer in the Debug mode. To invoke it, select a pointer variable in the debugger’s variables view and press `⌘Enter`.
>
> During stepping, if you have Memory View opened, CLion will highlight the memory changes that take place in the selected memory piece.

And here is what the memory view looks like:

[image: Memory view demo]

Comment: For the newcomers:  "show memory view" is only available for pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Latest (CLion 2018.1) has GDB in default layout.
and you at any point can see memory dump according to your taste (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html)

f.e. x/16ux &myVar